# Cordova plugin install and use in framework7

Tags: android, cordova, html-framework-7

I am developing an APP using cordova in Framework7. I need to get users active phoneNumber. So I have installed `cordova-plugin-telephonymanagerinfo` in Framework7 by using the following command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-telephonymanagerinfo
```

And it is installed perfectly. Now I am trying to use this plugin with the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    $(".page-content").text(JSON.stringify(TelephonyManagerInfo.phone));
}
```

It is not working. Any suggestion will appreciated.

Comment: Is there any issue on console?

Comment: No there is no issue

Comment: Connect the test device/emulator via adb bridge and view the logcat (native Android log) output for the application. Either use Android Studio or something like [Advanced Logcat Viewer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2454610)

Comment: Connect with device and check in chrome for issue , debuge that what is going here "TelephonyManagerInfo".